# Spring, switch property file depending on profile

Tags: spring, configuration

So i have a spring 4 application.
It contains 3 properties files:

```
application.properties
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
```

In the header of application.properties, i specify the profile i want:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

So in the two other files:

```
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
```

I have duplicate entries across them, so lets say in the dev file i have:
`host=foo`
and in prod i have:
`host=bar`
Spring then picks up the value according to the currently active profile.
In order to tell Spring where the files are, i have a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.base.package")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties", "classpath:application-dev.properties", "classpath:application-prod.properties" })
public class ServiceSpringConfiguration
{
  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
  {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
}
```

But i have noticed that in this way, Spring loads all properties from all files and will not allow duplicates, and just loads the one you ask for, regardless of the profile.
How can i tell Spring to load files according to the selected profile?
I would have expect Spring to scan the file name and try to match the profile name....

Btw i refer to the property like so:

```
@Value("${host}")
  private String       host;
```

Comment: Spring Boot does this for you, normal spring doesn't. So either use Spring Boot or use your own mechanism to build (additional) the property sources. If you are already using Spring Boot then remove the `@PropertySource` and let Spring Boot handle the loading (you don't need the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as well in that case).

Comment: Thank you, i have implemented the accepted answer and it works very well, but i will have a look at Spring Boot docs, thx for the advice,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One easy and simple solution is to use the value of the property 'spring.profiles.active' to load the right application.properties.

In your example, it would be like this :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.base.package")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties", "classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"})
public class ServiceSpringConfiguration
```

Be aware that this solution comes with a problem because you can have severals active spring profiles and it won't work anymore.

Another solution is to create severals configuration classes by profile :

```
@Configuration 
@Profile('dev')
@PropertySource("classpath:application-dev.properties")
public class Devconfiguration {
}
```

and

```
@Configuration 
@Profile('prod')
@PropertySource("classpath:application-prod.properties")
public class Prodconfiguration {
}
```

Comment: This was nice.. Saved me a lot of time.. I was struggling to load a property file with a different name and spring doesn't do profiling for that automatically.